# Cannot clone repo on windows fatal: unable to access. The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: windows-7, windows, git, http, clone

I have set up Gerrit repository on non-standard port 10002. I have generated my HTTP password in Gerrit. I can successfully clone this repo over HTTP protocol on Unix machines and on most of Windowses. However, I cannot clone it on some Windows instances (Windows 7):

```
$ git clone http://myusername@myGerrit.com:10002/my-repo
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://myusername@myGerrit.com:10002/my-repo': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Cloning over SSH works without any problem. I need HTTP clone working because I need to clone this repo's not only on many machines without my private key.

I have tried turning off Windows Firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials. Not working instances does not have any antivir installed.

How to check what is blockig repo connection?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722521/error-the-requested-url-returned-error-403-forbidden-while-accessing) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I have inspected access logs to my server. With Msysgit, version `Git-1.9.5-preview20150319` they was:

```
185.28.251.241 - - [28/May/2015:19:31:17 +0200] "GET /my-repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 458 "-" "git/1.9.5.msysgit.1"
185.28.251.241 - - [28/May/2015:19:31:22 +0200] "GET /my-repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 290 "-" "git/1.9.5.msysgit.1"
```

After I have downgraded Msysgit to previous version `Git-1.9.5-preview20141217`, repo can be successfully cloned. Access logs are then as follows:

```
185.28.251.241 - - [28/May/2015:19:42:08 +0200] "GET /my-repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 458 "-" "git/1.9.5.msysgit.0"
185.28.251.241 - - [28/May/2015:19:42:08 +0200] "GET /my-repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 1193 "-" "git/1.9.5.msysgit.0"
185.28.251.241 - - [28/May/2015:19:42:08 +0200] "POST /my-repo/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 80403 "-" "git/1.9.5.msysgit.0"
```

So the solution for me was do downgrade Msysgit to the [1.9.5-preview20141217](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217) or upgrade to [Git for Windows 2.x](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) - they both work.

Also, see [related issue](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/315).